# SELECT to show all distinct rows from the tables where value is not empty and select some extra columns from a table

Tags: sql-server, select, union

I need to write a `SELECT` query in SQL Server which uses a `JOIN` or `UNION` that selects distinct `ItmNo` or code rows from 3 tables `OnHand`, `Sale` and `Purchase`.

Here are the details of the tables I have and what I need. `ItmNo` and/or `Code` columns can be used as foreign keys to join the tables.

These are my tables:

Table `OnHand`:

```
ID           ItmNo     Code   Qty
----------------------------------
1            I001      001    100
2            I001      001     50
3            I003      003    300
```

Table `Sale`:

```
ID          ItmNo     Code   Qty
----------------------------------
1           I001      001    100
2           I004      004    
3           I003      003    120
```

Table `Purchase`:

```
ID          ItmNo     Code   Qty
----------------------------------
1           I005      005     10
2           I003      003    200
3           I003      003    300
```

And this is what I need as output. Only `DISTINCT` ItmNo and Code should be displayed here:

```
ID          ItmNo     Code   SumQtyOnHand    SumQtyOnSale    SumQtyOnPurchase
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           I001      001    150             100
2           I003      003    300             120             500
3           I005      005                                     10
```

Here is a working query to achieve the above

```
select 
    itemno, code, 
    sum(qtyOnHand) as SumQtyOnHand, 
    sum(qtyOnSale) as SumQtyOnSale, 
    sum(qtyOnPurchase) as SumQtyOnPurchase
from
    (select 
         itemno, code, qty as qtyOnHand, 
         null as qtyOnSale, null as qtyOnPurchase 
     from dbo.onhand
     union all 
     select itemno, code, null, qty, null from dbo.sale
     union all 
     select itemno, code, null, null, qty from dbo.purchase) t
group by 
    itemno, code
```

What if I have a couple of columns in `OnHand` that are not present in other tables `Sale` and `Purchase`? How can I select them in the query above with union all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to achieve what you want:

```
;WITH ALL_CTE AS
(
    SELECT 'OnHand' AS src, ItmNo, Code, Qty, Other
    FROM OnHand

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Sale' AS src, ItmNo, Code, Qty, 0
    FROM Sale

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Purchase' AS src, ItmNo, Code, Qty, 0
    FROM Purchase
)
SELECT 
     ItmNo
    , Code
    , SUM(CASE WHEN src = 'OnHand' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SumQtyOnHand    
    , SUM(CASE WHEN src = 'Sale' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SumQtySale
    , SUM(CASE WHEN src = 'Purchase' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SumQtyPurschase 
    , SUM(CASE WHEN src = 'OnHand' THEN Other ELSE 0 END) AS SumOtherOnHand   
FROM ALL_CTE
GROUP BY ItmNo, Code
```

The query uses `src` field to perform *conditional aggregation*. In this way you don't need to repeat `Qty` for each one of the tables. You can also easily add any extra fields from `OnHand` table.

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9c05a9/4)

Comment: I do not need the sum of the 'Other' field of OnHand. How can I select the value of this other field without the SUM (other) ?

Comment: @ShivamSantosh Then you can group by `Other` also

Comment: @ShivamSantosh This field may have different values within each `ItmNo`, `Code` group. In this case which one do you want to select?

Comment: @Charlieface . This 'Other' field is not an int field so I am unable to do that. Please suggest

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, I want to select the top row in that case. Please suggest

Comment: Sorry you just need to do `GROUP BY ItmNo, Code, Other`

Comment: @Charlieface That does not work for me as Other field is a varchar in my case and not an integer. Please suggest to select  the top row value of Other field in the query above if possible.

Comment: Completely confused. Do you want to group by the `Other` column, in other words, each distinct `Other` gets a new row? Then you can use `group by ..., Other` why shouldn't it work on varchar? Or do you want a kind of "just use the other grouping columns, and give *any* value for `Other` out of the group." In which case you can use either `MAX(Other)` or `MIN(Other)` on varchar columns, it will be the first/last value in A-Z order.